# Display date value in saturn material date range picker

Tags: angular

I have used saturn material date picker in order to select a range of date.

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date " [satDatepicker]="picker"  [value]="date">
     <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"> 
     </sat-datepicker>
    <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"> 
     </sat-datepicker-toggle>
</mat-form-field>
```

How to display the value of the selected dates?
I used `{{date.value}}` but didn't work! Please help.

Comment: I think you should change sat-datepicker to be mat-datepicker and the same for sat-datepicker-toggle

Comment: Actually rangeMode isnot a known property of mat-datepicker

Answer (score 5):

Your value you pass into the input needs be like:

```
let dateRangeDisp = {'begin': Date, 'end': Date};
```

So to get the date and display it right away:

```
// Template
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput
    [placeholder]="label"
    [satDatepicker]="picker"
    [value]="dateRangeDisp"
    (dateChange)="saveDate($event)">
  <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
  <sat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></sat-datepicker-toggle>
</mat-form-field>

// Code behind
saveDate(event: any) {
    // look at how the date is emitted from save
    console.log(event.target.value.begin);
    console.log(event.target.value.end);

    // change in view
    this.dateRangeDisp = event.target.value;

    // save date range as string value for sending to db
    this.field.value = new Date(event.target.value.begin) + "|" + new Date(event.target.value.end);
    // ... save to db
}

getDate() {
    // get your saved value from some service
    let savedRangeStr = someService.getSavedRange();

    /// now you retrieve the date value from db and format it correctly for display
    this.dateRangeDisp = {'begin': Date, 'end': Date};
    this.dateRangeDisp.begin = new Date(savedRangeStr.substring(0, savedRangeStr.indexOf("|")));
    this.dateRangeDisp.end = new Date(this.field.value.substring(savedRangeStr.indexOf("|") + 1, savedRangeStr.length));


  }
```